# How to start with Blender?

Tags: 3d, tutorial, education, blender, resource-recommendations

I'm very interested in animation however I only have a little bit experience in Flash Pro. I would like to start from Blender and how to make easy models then go higher and higher. Is there any book from which I can start from?

I know there are many tutorials on YouTube such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2uY7rjhhMs) but I prefer some solid book which will explain everything from the basics.

Comment: You might try the [Blender Stack Exchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com/) for this question :)

Comment: Ok Thanks, StackExchange have so many sub-website that I didn't know where to ask about blender so I asked here xD

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic tutorials on the Blender website.
Also, check this first:
http://www.panduaji.com/2013/01/3-common-newbie-problem-in-blender.html
You might want to reconfigure the left-click before you do anything else.  :)

Once you have an understanding, this guy is good: http://www.blenderguru.com/

Answer (score 0):

To learn the basics, go to [cgcookie.com/blender](http://cgcookie.com/blender) and then in the website go to `blender basics` to learn all the basics that you need for the program. And then you can go further with free tutorials like [blenderguru.com](http://blendguru.com) to enhance your skills. Then you can go to find a course site for tutorials like [cgcookie.com](http://cgcookie.com) and [blendercookie.com](http://blendercookie.com) to enhance your skills even further.